# Youtube Api playVideo method doesn't work on some mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, video, mobile, youtube

I am trying to create a website for mobile where after clicking on an image a youtube video to play.

I have tested on several Android mobile phones/versions and on some doesn't behaves as intended.

What I mean is it stops at buffering and never reaches to play the video. Another thing that I noticed is that the player works after the user triggers the video to play and not programatically. More detailed if I directly show the youtube player, the user click to play video and afterward click a button/image to play another video this works.

I have posted here the test page that I worked with [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryjzt82h/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// Caching jQuery objects
var $body = $('body'),
    $log = $('#log'),
    $yt = $('#ytplayer'),
    $ytwrap = $('#ytwrapper'),
    $choices = $('#choices');


// This code loads the YouTube API
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
$body.append(tag);

// This will become the player object when the API is ready
var player;

// See what kind of device we're using
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = userAgent.indexOf('android') > -1;
var isIpad = userAgent.indexOf('ipad') > -1;
var isIphone = userAgent.indexOf('iphone') > -1;


window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        videoId: videos[0],
        playerVars: {
            allowfullscreen: 'allowfullscreen',
            playsinline: 0
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });


    window.player = player;
    //hide player 
  slidePlayer(false);

};


function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

    // When a video starts playing,
    // enable the fake fullscreen mode on Android & iPad
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        if (isIpad) {
            fakeFullScreen(true);
        } else if (isAndroid) {
            fakeFullScreen(true);
        }
    }

    // On pause: hide the player, show thumbs
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {

        if (isAndroid) {
            // Exit fullscreen
            fakeFullScreen(false);

            // Scroll back to choices
            window.scrollTo(0, playerTop);
        } else if (isIpad) {
            fakeFullScreen(false);
            window.scrollTo(0, playerTop);
        } else if (isIphone) {
            slide(false);
        }
    }
}



$('#vstImageAd .imageWrap img').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    if (player) {

        $this.css("display", "none");
        slidePlayer(true);

        player.playVideo();
    }

});


// When a thumb image is pushed, start the video
$('#choices .playthumb img').click(function (e) {

    var $this = $(this),
        nr = parseInt($this.data('nr'));

    if (!videos[nr]) nr = 1;

    player.loadVideoById(videos[nr]);

    // Hide the thumbs
    slide(true);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like some functions you are using (player.playVideo()) are disabled in Mobile devices.
In my case after using player.playVideo() in some Android devices, the video isn´t played even after tapping the player

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=zh-TW#Mobile_considerations

> Autoplay and Scripted Playback
>
> The HTML5  element, in certain mobile browsers (such as Chrome
> and Safari), only allows playback to take place if it's initiated by a
> user interaction (such as tapping on the player).
>
> Due to this restriction, functions and parameters such as autoplay,
> playVideo(), loadVideoById() won't work in all mobile environments**